# rsync selected sub folders

Tags: linux, rsync, transfer

I want to transfer selective sub folders from a range of parent folders:

```
/home/user/sample_rsync/ 
FolderA/sub1
FolderA/sub2
FolderA/sub3
FolderB/sub1
FolderB/sub2
FolderB/sub3
FolderC/sub1
FolderC/sub2
FolderC/sub3
```

Say from the above example I want to copy just sub1 from each directory. i.e. in my destination I want the following folders to be created (along with the files they contain)

```
/destination/
sample_rsync/FolderA/sub1
sample_rsync/FolderB/sub1
sample_rsync/FolderC/sub1
```

How do I go about doing this?

I tried out

```
rsync -avh -f"- *" -f"+ *sub1/*" /home/user/sample_rsync /destination/
```

In an attempt to exclude everything and then just include sub1's - didnt work.

Any way I can get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your source folders are in a file called "sources" as typed in your first code sement (without trailing / characters)

```
for s in $(cat sources)
do
  rsync -av ${s} /destination/sample_rsync/$(echo ${s}| awk -F "/" '{print $1}')
done
```

of course this is only valid if you have a certain level deep directories in your sources file. If the depth level of the directories to be copied changes, this script will need to be heavily modified. But at least it is a starting point I hope.

upon your question below, you might want to use something like this: (ignore the code segment above. I just left it there for history purposes)

```
cd /home/user/sample_rsync
for dir in $(find ./ -type d -name sub1)
do
  dest=$(echo ${dir} | sed -e "1,1s+/sub1++")
  mkdir /destination/sample_rsync/${dest}
  rsync -av ${dir} /destination/sample_rsync/${dest}
done
```

please do not take it as the word of gospel. I have not tested the code whatsoever. So. it might yield some unexpected results. Please test it on a system that you wouldn't mind having problems if it gets haywire.

Comment: Sorry a bit new to linux, where exactly am i specifying that I just want to pull subfolders named "sub1"? Or does the file sources just contain the folders that I want to pull? If so, I wanted to avoid manually setting up a source file list.